# Update statement showing a blank space in the end

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-update, submit

When I submit the form to the Update function a blank line shows up in the page header, and then IF I print the update statement does not working, because in the end are showing some blank space, and if paste on text editor, as Toad, looks like there is an Hyphen. Check below picture

[image: After print and paste the function on Toad, there a hyphen, like invisible]

[image: Print the function]

```
      UPDATE style_schedule_image SET
                description = '1-Shoe Boxes - BULK'
            WHERE
                id = '116741';
```

Is this a issue on my code? I search on all my codes, and can not find it.

Php page

```
        <?php
            session_start();
            if(!$_SESSION["id_user"]){
                die(header("location: ../login.php"));
            }

            include('../_functions/parameters.php');
            include('../_functions/database_open.php');
            include('../_functions/functions.php');
            include("../_functions/translator.php");
            include('../_class/class_final_inspection.php');

            $uploaddir = '../croquis/style_cfm_picture/';

            $class_final_inspection = new class_final_inspection();

            include('../_library/_email/class_send_email.php');
            $send_email = new class_send_email();

            if (isset($_POST))
            {
                if ($_POST['FUNCAO'] == "PICTURE")
                {

                    $style_schedule = $class_final_inspection->select_open_final_inspection(
                        $_POST['id_inspection']
                    );

                    $select_picture = $class_final_inspection->query_picture(
                        $_POST['id_inspection']
                    );

                }

                if ($_POST['FUNCAO'] == "INSERT_PICTURE")
                {

                    $select_picture_for_update = $class_final_inspection->query_files_final_picture_for_update(
                        $_POST['id_inspection']
                    );  

                    $linha_total_pic = mysql_fetch_object($select_picture_for_update);  

                    $reg_total_txt = explode("#;", $_POST['text_dados']);

                    for ($id = 1; $id <= $linha_total_pic->total; $id++) {

                    $linha_ln = explode("|", $reg_total_txt[$id]);                  

                    $itens = $class_final_inspection->update_pictures(
                        $linha_ln[0],
                        $linha_ln[1]
                        );  
                    }

                }

                if ($_POST['FUNCAO'] == "DELETE_PICTURE")
                {
                    $openddir = '../../dotcom/croquis/final_inspection_pictures/';

                    unlink($openddir.$_POST['id_image'].".jpg");

                    $message = $select_picture = $class_final_inspection->delete_picture(
                        $_POST['id_image']
                    );

                    $style_schedule = $class_final_inspection->select_open_final_inspection(
                        $_POST['id_inspection']
                    );

                    $select_picture = $class_final_inspection->query_files_final_picture(
                        $_POST['id_inspection']
                    );
                }

                if ($_POST['FUNCAO'] == "SEND_EMAIL")
            {   
                $agora_vai = ($send_email->send_final_inspection_report(
                    $_POST['id_inspection'],
                    $_POST['vl_contacts']
                ));

                if($agora_vai == 'Email sent successfully!'){
                $update_email_sent = $class_final_inspection->update_email_sent(
                        $_POST['id_inspection']
                );}
            }

        }

        ?>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title><?php print $translator_title['FINALINSP']; ?></title>
                <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_library/_css/menu.css" >
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_library/_css/system.css" >
                <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../_library/_js/default.js"></script>
                <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../_library/_js/final_inspection.js"></script>
                <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=yes" name="viewport">
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
            </head>
            <body style="margin:0; background-color:#E4E4E4;">
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
                    <tr class="menu_title title_color"><td align="center" width="50px" onclick="back_to_menu();" ><img src="../_img/_back.png" width="30"></td><td align="center"><?php print $translator_title['FINALINSP']; ?> - <?php print $translator_title['PICTURE']; ?></td></tr>
                    <?php
                    if($agora_vai){

                        print '<tr><td class="field_options" align="center" style="text-align:center; background-color:#AEB9C5; font-size:20px;" colspan="3"><b>'.$agora_vai.'</b></td></tr>';

                        if($agora_vai == 'Email sent successfully!'){ print '<tr><td class="field_options" align="center" style="text-align:center; background-color:#AEB9C5; font-size:20px;" colspan="3">
                    <img style="cursor:pointer;" src="../_img/email_sended.png" width="100" height="120"</td></tr>'; }

                    }
                    ?>
                </table>
                <?php if($style_schedule){

                    $linha_schedule = mysql_fetch_object($style_schedule);
                ?>
                <form method="post" name="FORM_INSERT_SCHEDULE_PICTURE" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="hidden" name="FUNCAO" value="INSERT_PICTURE">
                <textarea class="textstyle" name="text_dados" style="display:none;"></textarea>
                <input type="hidden" name="id_image" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_inspection" value="<?php print $linha_schedule->id; ?>">
                <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">

                    <tr class="line_style_sub_title">
                        <td class="field_options" align="center" colspan="5" title="<?php print $orig_translator_title['SAVE']; ?>"><input type="submit" name="save" value="<?php print $translator_title['SAVE']; ?>" style="width:100px;" class="field_options" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    if($file)
                    {
                    if($message)

                    {
                    echo ' 
                    <div>
                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="width:200; background-color:green;">'.$orig_translator_title['PICTUREINSERTED'].'</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                    </div> ';

                    }
                    }
                    ?>
                </table>
                </form>
                    <div id="frame_comments">       
                    <iframe id="hts" name="frame_hts" id="frame_hts" border="0" style="display:none;"></iframe>
                    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
                    <tr class="line_style_sub_title">
                        <td class="field_options" align="center" colspan="5" title="<?php print $orig_translator_title['SENDEMAIL']; ?>"><input type="submit" onclick="check_contacts_email();" name="save" value="<?php print $translator_title['SENDEMAIL']; ?>" style="width:200px;" class="field_options"/></td>
                    </tr>   
                    </table>

                    </div>
                    <form method="post" name="FORM_SHOW_COMMENTS" action="" style="display:none;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="FUNCAO" value="SEND_EMAIL">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id_inspection" value="<?php print $linha_schedule->id; ?>">
                    </form>
                <?php 

                    print '
                    <center>
                    <div align="center" style="height:50%; border:none; width:90%; text-align:center;">
                    <table width="100%" align="center">
                        ';

                    $td_count = 1;

                    $openddir = '../croquis/final_inspection_pictures/';

                    while($linha_images = mysql_fetch_object($select_picture))
                    {
                        $components_ln = explode("#|",$linha_schedule->defect_description);

                        print' <tr>';

                        if($linha_images->type_comments == 'pdf'){
                        $openflie = '';
                        $openflie = $openddir.'Final Inspection Report - '.$linha_images->id_shipment_instruction.'.pdf' ; } else {
                            $openflie = '';
                        $openflie = $openddir.$linha_images->id.'.jpg' ;
                        }

                        $icon = $openddir.$linha_images->id.'.'.($linha_images->type_comments == 'jpeg' ? 'jpg' : 'jpg');
                        $edit_image = '<a title="Edit this image" href="../_library/_image/editor.php?id='.$linha_images->id.'|EDT&style_edit='.$_POST['style_edit'].'&upper='.$_POST['upper'].'&color='.$_POST['color'].'&seq='.$_POST['seq'].'" target="image_editor"><img src="../_img/image_edit.png" width="24" height="24" style="background-color:#A6A6A6; border-radius: 0.2em;"></a><br>';


                        if($linha_images->type_comments == 'pdf'){
                            $icon = '../_img/icon_pdf.png';
                            $edit_image = '';
                        }

                        print '<td align="right">

                                    <div style="float:right; vertical-align:bottom;">
                                        '.($linha_images->type_comments != 'pdf' ? '<img title="Delete this image" src="../_img/bg_remove.png" width="35" height="35" onclick="deleteImage('.$linha_images->id.');" style="background-color:#A6A6A6; border-radius: 0.2em; border:2px solid #FFFFFF;"><br>' : '').'

                                        </div>
                                    <div  style="float:right; vertical-align:bottom;"><a href="'.$openflie.'" target="_black" title="Click to open!"><img height="140px" width="140px" src="'.$icon.'"><a/>

                                    '.($linha_images->type_comments != 'pdf' ? 
                                    '


                                    <input type="hidden" id="picture_id_'.$td_count.'" value="'.$linha_images->id.'">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="description_'.$td_count.'" value="'.$linha_images->description.'">
                                    <td align="left">
                                    '.$linha_images->description.' <br>
                                    <select id="prod_sample_pictures_'.$td_count.'" name="prod_sample" class="textstyle_mobile" style="width:150px;" required>
                                        <option value="">::Select::</option>
                                    <optgroup label="BULK PRODUCTION PICTURES">
                                        <option value="1-Shoe Boxes - BULK">                                    '.$translator_title['SHOEBOX'].'</option>                   
                                        <option value="2-Pictogram - BULK">                                     '.$translator_title['PICTOGRAM'].'</option>
                                        <option value="3-Production Pairs Front - BULK">                        '.$translator_title['PRODUCTIONFRONT'].'</option>
                                        <option value="4-Production Pairs Side - BULK">                         '.$translator_title['PRODUCTIONSIDE'].'</option>
                                        <option value="5-Production Pairs Back - BULK">                         '.$translator_title['PRODUCTIONBACK'].'</option>
                                        <option value="6-Production pair with CFM Front - BULK">                '.$translator_title['PRODUCTIONCMFFRONT'].'</option>
                                        <option value="7-Production pair with CFM Side - BULK">                 '.$translator_title['PRODUCTIONCMFSIDE'].'</option>
                                        <option value="8-Production pair with CFM Back - BULK">                 '.$translator_title['PRODUCTIONCMFBACK'].'</option>

                                    <optgroup label="DEFECTS">

                                            '.($components_ln[2] != null || $components_ln[3] != null || $components_ln[4] != null ?        '<option value="9-Vamp crooked - DEFECT">                           '.$translator_title['VAMPCROOKED'].'</option>' : '').'
                                            '.($components_ln[5] != null || $components_ln[6] != null || $components_ln[7] != null ?        '<option value="10- Vamp not in pair - DEFECT">                     '.$translator_title['VAMPNOTINPAIR'].'</option>' : '').'
                                        </select></td>  





                                    </form>' : '').'



                                    </div></td>

                                    </tr>';
                        $td_count++;


                    }

                    print'  
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                    </center>';

                    } 
                ?>

            </body> 
        </html>
```

Class

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if(!$_SESSION["id_user"]){
        die(header("location: ../login.php"));
    }

    class class_final_inspection 
    {

       function select_final_inspection_quantity($po)
       {

            $query="
                select
                    factory.name as factory_name,
                    brand.name as brand_name,
                    po_item.po, 
                    po_item.seq,
                    po_item.upper_po, 
                    po_item.color_po,
                    style.id as style_id,
                    style.style,
                    style.name, 
                    style.customer_style_1, 
                    style.customer_style_2,
                    (po_item.pairs-ifnull(shipment_instruction.pairs,0)) as pairs
                from
                    po
                    inner join factory on
                        po.id_factory = factory.id
                    inner join brand on
                        po.id_brand = brand.id  
                    inner join po_item on
                        po.po = po_item.po  
                    inner join style on
                        po_item.id_style = style.id
                    left join
                        (
                        select 
                            shipment_instruction_item.po,
                            shipment_instruction_item.seq,
                            sum(shipment_instruction_item.pairs) as pairs
                        from
                            shipment_instruction
                            inner join shipment_instruction_item on
                                shipment_instruction.id = shipment_instruction_item.id_shipment_instruction
                        where
                            shipment_instruction.final_inspection is not null
                            and shipment_instruction.status = 'A'
                      and shipment_instruction.po = '".$po."'
                        group by
                            shipment_instruction_item.po,
                            shipment_instruction_item.seq
                        ) as shipment_instruction on
                    shipment_instruction.po = po_item.po and
                        shipment_instruction.seq = po_item.seq
                where
                    po.po = '".$po."'
                    and (po_item.pairs-ifnull(shipment_instruction.pairs,0)) > 0
                group by
                    po_item.po,
                    po_item.seq
                order by
                    style.id,
                    po_item.po,
                    po_item.seq

            ";

            return ($rs = mysql_query($query)) ? $rs : 'ERROR: '.mysql_error();
        }

        function open_final_inspetion($id_final_inspection)
        {

            $query="
                SELECT
                    style.id,
                    style_combination.sku_number,
                    style.customer_style_1  as customer_style,
                    style_schedule.id as style_schedule_id,
                    style_schedule.id_final_inspection as id_final,
                    style_combination.id as id_combination,
                    brand.name as brand_name,
                    factory.id as factory_id,
                    factory.name as factory_name,
                    season.short as season_short,
                    style.style,
                    users.id as user_id,
                    CASE WHEN style.name != '' THEN
                        style.name
                    WHEN style.customer_style_1 != '' THEN
                        style.customer_style_1
                    WHEN style.customer_style_2 != '' THEN
                        style.customer_style_2
                    END as style_name,
                    style_combination.upper as material, 
                    style_combination.color,
                    DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%d/%b/%y') as conf_date,
                    stage_status.status as status_name,
                    style_schedule.status,
                    style_schedule.comments,
                    UPPER(users.name) as user_name,
                    style_schedule.stage,
                    style_schedule.form_information
                FROM
                    style
                    inner join style_schedule ON
                        style.id = style_schedule.id_style
                    inner join style_combination ON
                        style_schedule.id_style_combination = style_combination.id
                    inner join factory ON 
                        style.id_factory = factory.id
                    inner join season ON 
                        style.id_season = season.id
                    inner join brand ON 
                        style.id_brand = brand.id
                    inner join stage_status ON
                        style_schedule.status = stage_status.id
                    left join users ON
                        style_schedule.id_user = users.id
                WHERE
                    style_schedule.id_final_inspection = '".$id_final_inspection."'
                ORDER BY
                    factory.name;

            ";


            return ($rs = mysql_query($query)) ? $rs : 'ERROR: '.mysql_error();
        }

        function query_picture($id_final_inspection){

            $query = "
            select
                style_schedule_image.*
            from
                style_schedule_image
            where
                style_schedule_image.id_schedule in (select id from style_schedule where style_schedule.id_final_inspection = '".$id_final_inspection."')
            order by type_comments
            ;";

            return ($rs = mysql_query($query)) ? $rs : 'ERROR: '.mysql_error();

        }

        function insert_file($id_schedule,$id_daily_inspection){

            $query="
                INSERT INTO style_schedule_image 
                (
                    id_schedule,
                    id_shipment_instruction,
                    type_comments,
                    description
                )
                VALUES 
                (
                    '".$id_schedule."',
                    '".$id_daily_inspection."',
                    'pdf',
                    'Final Inspection Report'
                )
            ";

            return ($rs = mysql_query($query)) ? $rs : 'ERROR: '.mysql_error();

        }


        function query_files_final_picture($id_final_inspection){

            $query = "
                select style_schedule_image.*,shipment_instruction.defect_description  FROM style_schedule_image left join shipment_instruction on shipment_instruction.id = style_schedule_image.id_shipment_instruction where style_schedule_image.id_shipment_instruction = '".$id_final_inspection."' order by type_comments;";


            return ($rs = mysql_query($query)) ? $rs : 'ERROR: '.mysql_error();

        }

        function query_files_final_picture_for_update($id_final_inspection){

            $query = "
                select count(*) as total FROM style_schedule_image where style_schedule_image.id_shipment_instruction = '".$id_final_inspection."' and type_comments = 'jpeg';
            ";


            return ($rs = mysql_query($query)) ? $rs : 'ERROR: '.mysql_error();

        }

        function query_files_final_report($id_final_inspection){

            $query = "
            select
                style_schedule_image.*
            from
                style_schedule_image
            where
                style_schedule_image.id_shipment_instruction = '".$id_final_inspection."'
                and style_schedule_image.type_comments = 'pdf';
            ";


            return ($rs = mysql_query($query)) ? $rs : 'ERROR: '.mysql_error();

        }

        function schedule_insert_picture($id_schedule,$id_shipment_instruction,$extension,$file_name,$description){

            $query="
                INSERT INTO style_schedule_image 
                (
                    id_schedule,
                    id_shipment_instruction,
                    type_comments,
                    title_comments,
                    description

                )
                VALUES 
                (
                    '".$id_schedule."',
                    '".$id_shipment_instruction."',
                    '".$extension."',
                    '".$file_name."',
                    '".$description."'
                )
            ";

            return (mysql_query($query)) ? mysql_insert_id() : 'ERROR: '.mysql_error();
        }

        function insert_final_inspection_file($id_shipment_instruction,$format,$type,$description,$prod_sample){

            $query="
                INSERT INTO final_inspection_files
                (
                    id_shipment_instruction,
                    format,
                    type,
                    description,
                    id_picture_final
                )
                VALUES 
                (
                '".$id_shipment_instruction."',
                '".$format."',
                '".$type."',
                '".$description."',
                '".$prod_sample."');
            ";

            return (mysql_query($query)) ? mysql_insert_id() : 'ERROR: '.mysql_error();
        }

        function delete_picture($id_image){

            $query="
                DELETE FROM
                    style_schedule_image 
                WHERE
                    style_schedule_image.id = '".$id_image."'
                ;
            ";


            return (mysql_query($query)) ? 'Deleted successfully!' : 'ERROR: '.mysql_error();

        }

        function select_open_final_inspection($id_final_inspection){

            $query = "
            select
                inspection_total.id,
                inspection_total.po,
                po_item.color_po as po_color,
                po_item.id_combination,
                style_combination.sku_number,
                inspection_total.total_pairs,
                CASE WHEN po.r_xftry IS NOT NULL THEN DATE_FORMAT(po.r_xftry,'%d/%b/%y') ELSE DATE_FORMAT(po.xftry,'%d/%b/%y') end as real_x_fac,
                brand.name as brand_name,
                CASE WHEN IFNULL(classification_faults.sample_size_percent,0) > 0 THEN
                    round(classification_faults.sample_size_percent*inspection_total.total_pairs/100)
                ELSE
                    classification_faults.sample_size
                END quantity_to_inspect,
                classification_faults.how_many_CR, 
                classification_faults.how_many_MJ, 
                classification_faults.how_many_MN,
                sum(classification_faults.how_many_MJ+classification_faults.how_many_MN ) as total_faults,
                DATE_FORMAT(inspection_total.final_inspection,'%d/%b/%y') as final_inspection_date,
                inspection_total.quantity_inspected,
                inspection_total.cartons_inspected,
                inspection_total.comments,
                inspection_total.defect_description,
                inspection_total.status,
          inspection_total.total_mn as total_mn,
          inspection_total.total_mj as total_mj,
          inspection_total.total_cr as total_cr,
          inspection_total.total_faults_inspec as total_faults_inspec,
                CASE WHEN inspection_total.status = 'A' THEN 
                    'APPROVED'
                WHEN inspection_total.status = 'R' THEN
                    'REJECTED'
                ELSE
                    ''
                END status_name,
                inspection_total.user_name
            from  
                (
                select
                    shipment_instruction.id,
                    shipment_instruction.po,
                    shipment_instruction.quantity_inspected,
                    shipment_instruction.cartons_inspected,
                    shipment_instruction.comments,
                    shipment_instruction.defect_description,
                    shipment_instruction.status,
                    users.name as user_name,
                    shipment_instruction.final_inspection,
                    sum(shipment_instruction_item.pairs) as total_pairs,
                    shipment_instruction.total_mn,
                    shipment_instruction.total_mj,
                    shipment_instruction.total_cr,
                    shipment_instruction.total_faults_inspec
                from 
                    shipment_instruction
                    inner join shipment_instruction_item on
                        shipment_instruction.id = shipment_instruction_item.id_shipment_instruction  
                    left join users on 
                        shipment_instruction.id_user = users.id
                where
                    shipment_instruction.id = '".$id_final_inspection."'
                group by
                    shipment_instruction.id,
                    shipment_instruction.po    
                ) as inspection_total
                inner join po on
                    po.po = inspection_total.po
                inner join po_item 
                    on po.po = po_item.po
                inner join brand on
                    po.id_brand = brand.id
                left join style_combination on 
                    style_combination.id = po_item.id_combination

                left join classification_faults on
                    classification_faults.ini_pairs <= inspection_total.total_pairs AND 
                    classification_faults.fin_pairs >= inspection_total.total_pairs;
                    ";
                    return ($rs = mysql_query($query)) ? $rs : 'ERROR: '.mysql_error();
        }


        function final_inspection_update_schedule($id_final_inspection,$id_user,$comments,$check_list,$status,$total_mn){

            $query="
            UPDATE style_schedule SET
                conf = now(),
                status = '".$status."',
                id_user = '".$id_user."',
                form_information = '".$check_list."',
                comments = '".$comments."'
            WHERE
                id_final_inspection = '".$id_final_inspection."';
            ";

            return ($rs = mysql_query($query)) ? 'Updated successfully!' : 'ERROR: '.mysql_error();

        }

        function update_pictures($id_inspection,$description){

            $query="
            UPDATE style_schedule_image SET
                description = '".$description."'
            WHERE
                id = '".$id_inspection."';
            ";
            print $query;
            return ($rs = mysql_query($query)) ? 'Updated successfully!' : 'ERROR: '.mysql_error();

        }

        function select_schedule_final($id_final_inspection){

            $query = "
            select
                style_schedule.id
            from
                style_schedule
            where
                style_schedule.id_final_inspection = '".$id_final_inspection."';
            ";

            return ($rs = mysql_query($query)) ? $rs : 'ERROR: '.mysql_error();
        }

        function schedule_id($id_final_inspection){

            $query = "
            select
                style_schedule.id
            from
                style_schedule
            where
                style_schedule.id_final_inspection = '".$id_final_inspection."';
            ";

            return ($rs = mysql_query($query)) ? $rs : 'ERROR: '.mysql_error();
        }



    }

    ?>
```

Comment: are you using php to get connection with mysql? if yes, i cannot see it in your code.

Comment: @Gurminder Sorry, i didnt add my code, please check now

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply run sql query in html.
You have to connect to sql with php

[Here you can find how to connect to sql database via php](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

[Here you can find how to update fields from html](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)